# Save graphs as GraphML

Tags: java, jgrapht, graphml

I'd like to save a graph created with JGraphT as a GraphML file.
This file should then be able to be opened with Gephi.
In the following code however, only one file is generated, which can not be opened with Gephi.

```
GraphMLExporter gmlExporter = new GraphMLExporter();       
File file = new File("test");
Writer fileWriter;      
fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));          
gmlExporter.exportGraph(g,fileWriter);
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: ok, I have found a solution.

Comment: GraphMLExporter<URL, DefauldEdge> gmlExporter = new GraphMLExporter();                                                                          
FileWriter PS = new FilterWriter("test.graphml"); gmlExporter.exportGraph(g, PS);